请审核一下我的想法有什么不对？
有这个题目：

如图所示，A车正在变更车道，以下说法正确的是什么？
A、该车没有违法行为
B、压实线变更车道
C、未按规定开启转向灯
D、未按规定车道行驶


就是，他问的是哪个是正确，而不是图片中有什么违法。现在我来解释一下我的想法。
A选肯定不正确，因为图片中的A车在压实现， 压实现是一种违法行为。
B选正确，因为在图中A车的确在压实现变更车道。
D选我觉得不正确。图中的A车可以在它的原来的车道行驶，也可以它想变更的那个车道行驶。所以，它按规定车道行驶。
C选是我的问题。A车开启了转向灯。在中间的车道开启转向灯表示它打算变更车道，但它不可以变更车道，所以开启转向灯也不准许。因此我觉得 ”未按规定开启转向灯“ 这个说法是正确。
按照驾考宝典，只有B选是正确。我的想法有什么不对？
这个网页解释为什么B选是正确，而没有为什么其他选不是。

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about the Chinese language.

Unless we consider the question and the answer options as a general test of one's understanding of the Chinese words and phrases in a situational context?

@WayneCheah, 感谢你的支持。假如这是一个HSK的题目，我觉得区别不大。

Once you know that crossing the solid line is against the road laws, then the question seems to be about justifying why C 未按规定开启转向灯 is (in)correct.   [Hmm... the logic seems to be: (a) The law requires you to do X and not do Y.  (b) You do both X and Y simultaneously.  (c) Was X not performed in accordance with the law?]

开启转向灯规定 mandates turning on your turn signal when making turns or changing lanes (whether legal or illegal) to alert the incoming or traffic behind. The main purpose of this regulation is to avoid collisions (追撞 in this case).
In other words, if this driver didn't turn on the turn signal, he might have received two citations 1. illegally changing lanes, and 2. changing lanes without flashing the turn signal.
Now let's move on to the question:
"....以下说法正确的是什么" - According to the photo, which of the descriptions below is correct (in the sense of matching the photo shown)?

B、压实线变更车道 (True, wheel on the solid median strip while intending to change lanes - the flashing turn signals and the direction of the front tire tell the intention)

C、未按规定开启转向灯 (False, the yellow turn signals are on as required for making turns and changing lanes)



whether legal or illegal - 这是个关键，现在我理解了，谢谢您！

Glad to be helpful.
